# how to enable/disable selection of rows on a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Which method can I call to enable/disable the possibility
 of select rows in a JTable?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[JTable#setRowSelectionAllowed(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionAllowed-boolean-)